# python как унаследовать параметр во все классы

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, атрибуты

у меня есть дочерние классы, всего их **`4`** в качестве примера один - `child1()`.

Также есть главный класс, который инициализируется, и в который передается некий `param`.

**Вопрос 1**: Как при инициализации главного класса прокинуть/передать `param` в дочерние классы, так что бы  дочерний класс мог узнать значение из главного как на примере `printParam()`?

**Вопрос 2**: Таких параметров будет около **`10`**-ти, также у дочернего класса может быть еще дочерний класс.

Что стоит почитать/посмотреть чтобы лучше разобраться в этом?

```
class child1(): #Унаследовать param из main класса
def __init__(self): 
        self.param = param 

def printParam(self):
        print(self.param)
```

```
class MainClass(child1):
    def __init__(self, param): 
        self.param = param

mn = MainClass(param='param')
```

Comment: Унаследовать в каком смысле - иметь доступ к одному общему значению для всех дочерних классов? А это значение будет меняться потом или нет? Вариантов то много как это сделать, вы лучше скажите - зачем вам это, может вообще нужно что-то другое на самом деле.

Comment: Значение меняться не будет, да, нужно иметь доступ к одному общему значению из главного для всех дочерних классов. 
Это нужно что бы мои классы разных api могли получить доступ к одному прокси.

Comment: а чем приведенный код не устраивает?

Comment: Так используйте переменную класса тогда для этого, например.

Comment: Эникейщик, каким образом приведенный код может получить из главного класса параметр в дочерним?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Child1(): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.objectName = 'child1' 
        self.param = parent.param 

    def print_param(self):
        print(f'{self.objectName:>8}: {self.param}')
        
        
class Child2_1(): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.objectName = 'child2_1' 
        self.param = parent.param 

    def print_param(self):
        print(f'{self.objectName:>8}: {self.param}')
        
        
class Child2(): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.objectName = 'child2' 
        self.param = parent.param 
        
        self.child2_1 = Child2_1(parent)

    def print_param(self):
        print(f'{self.objectName:>8}: {self.param}')
        

class MainClass():
    def __init__(self, param): 
        self.param = param
        
        self.child1 = Child1(self)
        
        self.child2 = Child2(self)


mn = MainClass(param='param777')

mn.child1.print_param()
mn.child2.print_param()
mn.child2.child2_1.print_param()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**:

```
class Child1(): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.objectName = 'child1' 
        self.parent = parent

    def print_param(self):
        print(f'{self.objectName:>8}: {self.parent.param}')
        
        
class Child2_1(): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.objectName = 'child2_1' 
        self.parent = parent

    def print_param(self):
        print(f'{self.objectName:>8}: {self.parent.param}')
        
        
class Child2(): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.objectName = 'child2' 
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.child2_1 = Child2_1(parent)

    def print_param(self):
        print(f'{self.objectName:>8}: {self.parent.param}')
        

class MainClass():
    def __init__(self, param): 
        self.param = param
        
        self.child1 = Child1(self)
        
        self.child2 = Child2(self)


mn = MainClass(param='param777')

mn.child1.print_param()
print()

mn.param = 555
mn.child2.print_param()
mn.child2.child2_1.print_param()
mn.child1.print_param()
print()

mn.param = 567
mn.child2.child2_1.print_param()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]